# Is it possible to send data to a minimized window use pywinauto?

Tags: pywinauto

Several months ago, I wrote a Python GUI app that reads a file containing vehicle data.  It then uses the sendkeys module to enter the data on a green house gas model app.  I've converted the code to use pywinauto and use the application module in pywinauto to start the green house gas app.

I would like to have the green house gas application window in the background or minimized when data is being sent to it.  I am concerned that a user will try to close the window or wonder what is going on if the green house gas window is displayed.

I use the following functions in the python win32gui module to minimize the green house gas app window:

## hndl is the handle to the green house gas window I found using win32gui.EnumWindows()

win32gui.ShowWindow(hndl,win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)

## Set the focus

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hndl)

When I added the code above, the green house gas app window is minimized.  Unfortunately, the SendKeys module in pywinauto doesn't send information to a minimized window.

Is there any way around this?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`TypeKeys()` or the `SendKeysCtypes()` (current versions of `pywinauto` use this module for sending key strokes) module cannot be used. This is because they use the `SendInput` win API which just works with the active application (and the application will not be active if it is minimized.

That said the following may be useful:
Change an Edit text:

```
app.Dialog.Edit.SetEditText("Your Text")
```

Click a button or Checkbox, etc:

```
app.Dialog.ButtonEtc.Click()
```

These can work with the application being in the background. I tried hiding the window - but the above didn't work :( (because by default most of pywinauto is trying to ensure that the window is visible + Enabled.

To get a hidden window you can use:

```
hidden_win = app.window_(title = "Untitled - Notepad", visible_only = False)
```

and to get a child window - something like:

```
edit_control = hidden_win.ChildWindow(visible_only = False, class_name = "Edit")
```

But then unfortunately - you are a bit stuck when using pywinauto (because `edit_control.SetEditText(...)` will check that the window is visible :( )

Here is some hacked together code that will more or less work to set the value of an edit text (note SetEditText & Select are both copied from pywinauto - and changed slightly so that:

1. they do not check that the control is visible
2. they are standalone functions

Code:

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))
print sys.path[-1]
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import win32defines
from pywinauto import win32functions
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
import time
import ctypes

#-----------------------------------------------------------
def Select(win, start = 0, end = None):
    "Set the edit selection of the edit control"

    # if we have been asked to select a string
    if isinstance(start, basestring):
        string_to_select = start
        #
        start = win.TextBlock().index(string_to_select)

        if end is None:
            end = start + len(string_to_select)

    if end is None:
        end = -1

    win.SendMessageTimeout(win32defines.EM_SETSEL, start, end)

    # give the control a chance to catch up before continuing
    win32functions.WaitGuiThreadIdle(win)

    time.sleep(Timings.after_editselect_wait)

    # return this control so that actions can be chained.
    return win

#-----------------------------------------------------------
def SetEditText(win, text, pos_start = None, pos_end = None):
    "Set the text of the edit control"
    # allow one or both of pos_start and pos_end to be None
    if pos_start is not None or pos_end is not None:

        # if only one has been specified - then set the other
        # to the current selection start or end
        start, end = win.SelectionIndices()
        if pos_start is None:
            pos_start = start
        if pos_end is None:
            pos_end = end

        # set the selection if either start or end has
        # been specified
        win.Select(pos_start, pos_end)
    else:
        Select(win)

    # replace the selection with
    text = ctypes.c_wchar_p(unicode(text))
    win.SendMessageTimeout(win32defines.EM_REPLACESEL, True, text)

    win32functions.WaitGuiThreadIdle(win)
    time.sleep(Timings.after_editsetedittext_wait)

    # return this control so that actions can be chained.
    return win

# this may be useful if you just want to send a keydown/keyup combination
def keystroke(hwnd, key):
    win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0)
    win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, key, 3 < 30)


app = application.Application.start('notepad')

# hide the window
win32gui.ShowWindow(app.window_(title = "Untitled - Notepad", visible_only = False).handle, win32defines.SW_HIDE)
print "See it is hidden :)"
time.sleep(2)

# get tehe edit control and set it's text
edit = app.window_(title = "Untitled - Notepad", visible_only = False).ChildWindow(visible_only = False, class_name = "Edit")
SetEditText(edit, "The edit text has been set")

# show the window again
win32gui.ShowWindow(app.window_(title = "Untitled - Notepad", visible_only = False).handle, win32defines.SW_SHOW)
```

This is a great example of how pywinauto could be improved (by providing a lower level library that would make it easier to do stuff like this)

Comment: Thank you Mark for your quick reply.